# Pyspark application with jar dependency

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, pypi, python-poetry

I'm trying to understand how you might develop a codebase that uses pyspark and scala-spark on Databricks. We have built a number of scala-spark utility libraries that we'd like to expose to pyspark applications. We understand how to interop between the scala and python sparkContexts.

However, we're struggling with how we might package and ship an application that has both a jar and a dependent py-wheel. Our jar's are hosted on maven and we use PyPi to manage python packages.

My initial thought was to declare the jar's in the python app making them artefacts of the python wheel that gets shipped to Databricks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what type of utilities or code you are trying to use across the two language runtimes? And is there any multi-threading involved in your code?